# Is it known what the intervening MP was saying when Swarbrick retorted "OK, boomer"?

Tags: parliament, new-zealand, rhetoric

In relation to [another question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/47455/has-new-zealand-announced-any-investigation-or-punishment-censure-for-mp-swarbic) of mine, New Zealand Green Party MP [said that](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2017/may/15/australian-millionaire-millennials-avocado-toast-house)

> "Today I have learnt that **responding succinctly and in perfect jest to somebody heckling you about *your age*** as you speak about the impact of climate change on *your generation* with the literal title of their generation makes some people very mad," she wrote. "So I guess millennials ruined humour. That, or we just need to pull ourselves up by our bootstraps and abstain from avocados."
>
> "That’s the joke," she added.

So Swarbrick seems to be saying in her defence that she was being heckled for her age by the other MP. Alas, his [I presume] voice is inaudible in the video recording. Is it known however from any other source what he said to Swarbrick right before she retorted?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the exchange [went like this](https://www.newshub.co.nz/home/politics/2019/11/insults-fly-at-zero-carbon-bill-reading-as-mp-takes-shot-at-obnoxious-shane-jones.html)

> Swarbrick had been talking about how for decades world leaders have "known what is coming but have decided that it is more politically expedient to keep it behind closed doors".
>
> The 25-year-old MP said her generation and the generations after "do not have that luxury".
>
> "In the year 2050 I will be 56 years old, yet right now, the average age of this 52nd Parliament is 49 years old."
>
> The unnamed heckler said "that's impossible".
>
> "OK, Boomer," Swarbrick replied [...]

According to [another source](https://www.stuff.co.nz/national/politics/117211240/did-green-mp-chloe-swarbrick-kill-the-ok-boomer-meme) (which confirms the line) the intervening MP was

> reportedly National's Todd Muller, although Hansard did not record the MP's identity.

Comment: In case anyone was wondering who is right about the average age of Parliament: in Oct 2017 it was 49.  https://www.rnz.co.nz/news/the-wireless/374950/parliament-has-some-fresh-faces-but-the-stats-tell-a-different-story